# rspec it block inside loop

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to test that every link on a page returns a certain status code. I have a working test, something like this:

```
it "does not throw 400/500 error for any link" do
  visit '/'
  within(".wrapper") do
    all('a').each do |link|
      http_status = Faraday.head(link[:href].to_s).status
      puts "#{link.text}, #{http_status}"
      expect((400..500)).not_to include(http_status) 
    end
  end
```

However this is pretty terrible for output since all the links are checked in one test (hence the puts inside the test to show me which link breaks the test). I would like to be able to have a separate test for each link, without manually writing a test for every single link on the page.

I tried this:

```
context "does not throw 400/500 error for any link" do
  visit '/'
  within(".wrapper") do
    all('a').each do |link|
      it "does not throw 400/500 error for #{link}" do
        link_status_code_is_not(link, (400..500))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and got this error

```
`visit` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or
`context` block). It is only available from within individual examples 
(e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an 
example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).
```

so i tried moving the visit to a before hook but got the same issue with the within block (which I can't really move). I've been able to do something like this in jasmine, but I can't seem to find a way to do it in rspec.

tl:dr; Is there any way to put an it block inside a loop in rspec?

Comment: [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/4yd0ly/automation_testing_is_it_possible_to_loop_through/) might help you. It seems you can do it if you use a describe block instead a context one.

Comment: I do it all the time.  Why can't you have the `visit` within the `it` block?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I can have the visit within the it block, but that's not the issue. I'm trying to move everything except the http status check outside the it block so that there's a new it block for every link on the page.

Comment: How much links are there? Rather than doing this, directly make an array having link names as a `string`, it will be more useful.

Comment: @Rhunal How would I gather those links though? I can't use the visit or withing functions outside of an it block. I could try using selenium directly to read data from the page and then test that, but that seems like the wrong way to go about it. I'm quite surprised there isn't a simple way to do this all within rspec. I was able to do something similar with jasmine quite easily.

Comment: @con yes, you can not use `within` , `visit` outside the `describe` block. Try something like I have suggested above. If you know the `link`names then it will only help you to achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

You can create an `it` block inside of a loop:

```
RSpec.describe "numbers" do
  [*1..10].each do |number|
    it "#{number} should not be multiple of 10" do
      expect(number % 10).not_to be_zero
    end
  end
end
```

Your problem though is it doesn't look like you can `visit` outside of an `it` block (or "constructs that run in the scope of an example") and you need to grab your data from a page that you `visit` and loop through and create `it` blocks from that data. I'm not sure if that can be done nicely.

If what you're wanting is just better output for your links, you can use [`aggregate_failures`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/expectation-framework-integration/aggregating-failures) along with [Customized messages](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/customized-message) to provide a better output for your test. For a contrived example, let's say I have a ton of dynamic, only available within `it` blocks or from constructs that run in the scope of an example, pairs of numbers and I need to make sure none of their products are multiples of 10:

```
RSpec.describe "numbers" do
  it "are not a multiple of 10" do
    [*1..10].product([*1..10]).each do |base, multiplier|
      expect((base * multiplier) % 10).not_to be_zero
    end
  end
end
```

The output here isn't very good, it just tells me **expected `0.zero?` to return false, got true**, not which pair of numbers failed. By using the aggregate failures and a custom message though, I can fix that:

```
RSpec.describe "numbers" do
  it "are not a multiple of 10" do
    aggregate_failures do
      [*1..10].product([*1..10]).each do |base, multiplier|
        expect((base * multiplier) % 10).not_to be_zero, "#{base} * #{multiplier} is a multiple of 10"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I get only 1 failure reported in the stats (which may be good or bad for your use case), but I get 27 sub failures:

```
Failures:

  1) numbers are not a multiple of 10
     Got 27 failures from failure aggregation block.

     1.1) Failure/Error: ...
            1 * 10 is a multiple of 10
          # ...backtrace...
     1.2) Failure/Error: ...
            2 * 5 is a multiple of 10
          # ...backtrace...
     ...
     1.27) Failure/Error: ...
             10 * 10 is a multiple of 10
```

Comment: This is close, but the problem is I can't see the progress of the test. There are tons of links on the page so this one tests takes about 30 seconds to complete. I'd really like to break the check for each link into it's own test. I can do it easily with jasmine by calling a function which contains an it block from a loop within a describe block, but that doesn't seem to be allowed in rspec. Thank you for your help though!